# Angular for production

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have problems accessing the index that gives me 00 build because nothing appears in this and when I'm running it with the service of 00 runs without any problem

angular server:

[image]

with the index of angular build:

[image]

with live server extesion of VCS:
[image]

index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TareasProgramacion</title>
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.1b7bfbd029877df356d6.css">
</head>

<body>

    <app-root></app-root>
    <script src="runtime-es2015.858f8dd898b75fe86926.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="polyfills-es2015.27661dfa98f6332c27dc.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="runtime-es5.741402d1d47331ce975c.js" nomodule></script>
    <script src="polyfills-es5.7f43b971448d2fb49202.js" nomodule></script>
    <script src="scripts.51a5b3dbe9c8078dd7be.js"></script>
    <script src="main-es2015.d188a214c27c5ad765e8.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="main-es5.fb1dcf6aefa7d475bab0.js" nomodule></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to use a server to serve your `index.html` file. Read the error logs in your console.

Comment: Update the question and pick it up with live-server

Comment: Can you paste your `index.html` file from the dist folder here?

Comment: ready, updated!!!

Comment: I see a reference to `<base href="/">`. Can you try to build using `ng build --prod --base-href .` NOTE: There is a `.` in the end

Comment: you need to deploy the result of webpack bundling, to a server that can serve static files (and put in the root folder of the server), read https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Comment: Do you mean adding './' to each script?

Comment: `ng build` with `--base-ref` will do that for you. More info here: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-base-tag

Comment: @PsyGik thank you very much helped me a lot one more consultation, at the production level, would that affect the performance of the page?

Comment: The base href property does not have any performance implications. You can refer this checklist for improving performance. https://github.com/mgechev/angular-performance-checklist

Answer (score 0):

When the base tag is mis-configured, the app fails to load and the browser console displays 404 - Not Found errors for the missing files. Look at where it tried to find those files and adjust the base tag appropriately.

A simple solution: Change your base href when you build.

```
ng build --prod --base-href .
```

Now you can load the index.html file and it should work.

More info regarding the base href property here: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-base-tag